# Get rid of extra unwanted complexTypes from code-first generated WSDL - CXF with JAXB binding

Tags: java, wsdl, jaxb, jax-ws, cxf

I am attempting to clean up some JAX-WS annotated code-first web services such that they produce optimal and clean wsdl files for any implementing clients.  I've ran in to a problem where one of the classes that is being used a parameter (both in and out) in a particular webservice extends from `HashMap<String,String>`. Without using any kind of adapter, this produces xml in the wsdl that looks like the following:

```
<xs:complexType abstract="true" name="abstractMap">
 <xs:sequence/>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="hashMap">
 <xs:complexContent>
   <xs:extension base="tns:abstractMap">
     <xs:sequence/>
   </xs:extension>
 </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="attributeSet">
 <xs:complexContent>
   <xs:extension base="tns:hashMap">
     <xs:sequence/>
   </xs:extension>
 </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

We've got a JAXB adapter class that we are using and we are specifying this adapter on the JAX-WS annotated interface itself, which makes the  defined in the wsdl for these operations use the proper type and not this rather useless type hierarchy above.  The JAX-WS annotated method looks like this:

```
void assignPrincipalToRole(@WebParam(name="principalId") String principalId, 
    @WebParam(name="namespaceCode") String namespaceCode, 
    @WebParam(name="roleName") String roleName, 
    @WebParam(name="qualifications") @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value = AttributeSetAdapter.class) AttributeSet qualifications)
```

However, I'm noticing that type hierarchy for attributeSet, hashMap, and abstractMap types are still being defined within the WSDL even though no other types extend from them via  and the types aren't used anywhere else in the wsdl.

Now, I can do something like marking the AttributeSet class as @XmlTransient

```
@XmlTransient
public class AttributeSet extends HashMap<String,String> {
```

And this keeps `<xs:complexType name="attributeSet">` out of the WSDL, as expected, but yet `<xs:complexType name="hashMap">` and  `<xs:complexType abstract="true" name="abstractMap">`still remain in the wsdl.

Perhaps I'm being too obsessive, but having these types still in the WSDL is just ugly and misleading, but I can't quite tell why they are being included at all or how to remove them from the WSDL entirely.  This is where I need some help - how do I get rid of Map and AbstractMap from my wsdl types while still using AttributeSet in my code first interface?

If it helps I'm using Apache CXF 2.3.1 as my JAX-WS implementation with JAXB binding... though I don't know if CXF has anything to do with WSDL generation.

**Disclaimer**: I try to advocate and practice WSDL-first SOAP development every chance I get... however, the particular project I'm working on that lead to this question has decided on going code-first development for their SOAP services and I personally have no control over this matter.

---

**Edit**: Here's a copy/paste of the AttributeSet class (without the @XmlTransient, since I have reverted changing that due to it not doing much good).  All it is really is just an explicitly named class for a Map with an added method for formatted output.

```
public class AttributeSet extends HashMap<String,String> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5960854367616060667L;

    public AttributeSet() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * Create an AttributeSet with a single key/value pair.
     */
    public AttributeSet( String key, String value ) {
        this();
        put( key, value );
    }

    /**
     * @see HashMap#HashMap(int)
     * 
     * @param initialSize
     */
    public AttributeSet( int initialSize ) {
        super( initialSize );
    }

    public AttributeSet( Map<String,String> map ) {
        super();
        if ( map != null ) {
            putAll( map );
        }
    }

    public String formattedDump( int indent ) {
        int maxKeyLen = 1;
        for ( String key : this.keySet() ) {
            if ( key.length() > maxKeyLen ) {
                maxKeyLen = key.length();
            }
        }
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        String indentStr = StringUtils.repeat( " ", indent );
        for ( String key : this.keySet() ) {
            sb.append( indentStr );
            sb.append( StringUtils.rightPad( key, maxKeyLen, ' ' ));
            sb.append( " --> " );
            sb.append( get( key ) );
            sb.append( '\n' );
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the code in your AttributeSetAdapter class?

Comment: modified - see updated question.

Comment: Tested with CXF 2.7.3 and got same result, @whaley did you find solution?

Comment: @Betlista No, I never did - I ended up just ignoring it.